# How to get KMeans's inertia_ value after using Pipline

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to combine `StandardScaler()` and `KMeans()` by using Pipeline and also check the `kmeans`'s `inertia_` because I want to check which number of cluster is best.
The code is as following:

```
ks = range(3, 5)
inertias = []
inertias_temp = 9999.0
for k in ks:
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=rng)
    pipeline = make_pipeline(scaler, kmeans)
    pipeline.fit(X_pca)
    labels = pipeline.predict(X_pca)
    np.round(kmeans.cluster_centers_, decimals=3)
    inertias.append(kmeans.inertia_)
if (kmeans.inertia_ < inertias_temp):
    n_clusters_min = k
    kmeans_min = kmeans
    inertias_temp = kmeans.inertia_
```

However, I think that maybe the value of `kmeans.inertia_` is not correct because it should be got after `pipeline.predict()`. But I have no way to get this value after `pipeline.predict()`. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to observe the inertia distance of the cluster run from the `make_pipeline` instance. However, it is not necessary to perform `.predict()` to observe the distance of the number of centroids. To access the inertia value in your case, you may type as below:

`pipeline.named_steps['kmeans'].inertia_`

And then process it as you like!

---

Moreover, I had some free time, so I rewrote the code for you a little bit to make it more interesting:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
cluster = KMeans(random_state=1337)
pipe = make_pipeline(scaler, cluster)

centroids = []
inertias = []
min_ks = []
inertia_temp = 9999.0

for k in range(3, 5):
    pipe.set_params(cluster__n_clusters=k)
    pipe.fit(X_pca)
    centroid = pipe.named_steps['cluster'].cluster_centers_
    inertia = pipe.named_steps['cluster'].inertia_        
    centroids.append(centroid)
    inertias.append(inertia)

    if inertia < inertia_temp:
        min_ks.append(k)
```

Thank you for the question!

Comment: Thanks a lot! you are so nice!

Comment: Yeah. No problem.